# C program concept

Tags: c

I'm sorry if this question seems very noobish.

I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to approach this problem.

Here's the basic idea in code:

```
  int iterator = 0;

  if ((iterator % 2) == 1){
    // do first option
    iterator++;
    return;
  } else if ((iterator % 2) == 0){
    // do second thing
    iterator++;
    return;
  } else if ((iterator % 3) == 0){
    // do third option
    iterator++;
    return;
  } else{
    // error
    return;
  }
```

Essentially the function will be called once a second (it's a watchapp for Pebble).

**I can get the first two options to work but i'm having trouble with the third**. I assume it's because of the % 3 being too vague.

How would you guys approach this?

Comment: What do you actually want to do? Nothing vague about %3. You never get to it because first two options cover all numbers.

Comment: You should check %3 before you check %1.

Comment: @sashkello Basically it's watchapp that breaks down the time into chunks and display a chunk each second. So 'one twenty five' would be displayed as 'one' 'twenty' 'five' a word a second. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
if ((iterator % 3) == 0){
    // do first option
} else if ((iterator % 3) == 1){
    // do second thing
} else if ((iterator % 3) == 2){
    // do third option
} 
iterator++;
```

This can be re-written as:

```
switch (iterator++ % 3) {
case 0:
     // first option
     break;
case 1: 
     // second option
     break;
case 2: 
     // third option
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You never get to the third option, because iterator % 2 can be either 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

the %2 will give you only two options.

you could also try a different structure

```
switch ( iterator%3 )
{
  case 0: // option 0
    break;
  case 1: // option 1
    break;
  case 2: // option 2
    break;
  default:
    break; 
}
++iterator;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can't believe I got so stuck with this. Coffee is required.